# QMetaObject::invokeMethod does not call slot

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qmetaobject

I have a public signal called UpdateScreenshots in the workspacemanager class that takes screenshots of some widgets. It then returns these screenshots in a struct I've defined. This call is made from a thread as taking screenshots can apparently only be done on the main thread. However, this invokemethod call is not working and the updatescreenshots slot is not being called. What could I be doing wrong?
Is there a better way to do this?

invokeMethod call

```
VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct info;

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_Manager, "UpdateScreenshots", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
Q_RETURN_ARG(Vms::GuiWidgets::VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct, info));
```

The definition of the slot;

```
public slots:

/**
* \brief Updates the current screenshots to be sent to a remote client
*/
InfoStruct UpdateScreenshots() const;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have this declaration at the bottom of the `InfoStruct` header:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Vms::GuiWidgets::VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct)
```

Then, on top of your `main` function, have this call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Vms::GuiWidgets::VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct>("Vms::GuiWidgets::VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct");
```

Since you're using namespaces, you must be **very** consistent with them, so be sure the slot signature is like this:

```
Vms::GuiWidgets::VmsWorkspaceManager::InfoStruct UpdateScreenshots() const;
```